# Social Impact projects

Tags: open-source, self-improvement, contribution

I'm working at a software consultancy that a has a lot of volunteers available for about a month and a half at a time (when we're between projects and learning things) and we'd like to start contributing to open source projects that have a positive social impact. Any idea  which projects we can look at?

The constraints are:

- Built on a fairly modern language and stack that's suitable for beginners but has wide adoption - Java+Spring+Hibernate / RoR / Groovy+Grails - basically a stack we'd expect to work on in other projects too.
- Has / aims to have a positive on peoples lives - like Ushahidi, OpenMRS, RapidFTR, FrontlineSMS, etc.
- Has well defined stories and requirements, or has owners who are willing to work with our analysts to come up with them.

Any ideas?

Comment: You ask, "Any idea which projects we can look at?" and then go about mentioning some of the open sourced social impact project yourself - OpenMRS, RapidFTR, FrontlineSMS etc. Confused! What is it that you are asking for or wanting to know? May you please refine your question.

Comment: I'm trying to see what other projects fit into that category. Are these the only ones?

Comment: http://labs.google.com/sets?hl=en&q1=Ushahidi&q2=OpenMRS&q3=RapidFTR&q4=FrontlineSMS&q5=&btn=Large+Set

Comment: I do not like the idea of doing charity while on the company's clock. It is bad economics.

Comment: @Job: The OP said that the people are volunteers. Therefore it is not a question of good/bad economics (disregarding for the moment that charity is, from a naive viewpoint, always bad economics, but valuable and admirable nonetheless)

Comment: The company encourages this - it's part of our plan to give back to  society.

Answer (score 2):

You could look into [distributed social networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_social_network), like Diaspora or Appleseed.  Having monoliths like Facebook or Google controlling our online interactions could/has lead to bad places.

Answer (score 1):

I am not deeply familiar with the projects promoted there, but https://www.engineeringforchange.org/ aims to offer people an easy way to connect with humanitarian projects in all aspects of engineering - they have a section on 'Info Systems', I suspect that one or more of those projects will fit your interests.